# PHP/Symfony2 Form Checkbox field

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

Orm

```
My\SampleBundle\Entity\Subject:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:

        // ...

        motion:
            type: smallint
            unsigned: true
```

Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('motion', 'checkbox', array(
        'required'  => false
    ));

    // ...
}
```

Error

> Expected argument of type "Boolean", "integer" given

---

I would like to turn on and off by a check box. 
The value is distributed by 0 and 1.
It was useless even if it gave the value parameter.

```
$builder->add('motion', 'checkbox', array(
    'value'     => 1,
    'required'  => false
));
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your ORM mapping definition, you have to define `motion` as a boolean instead of a smallint. And FYI, Symfony interprets TINYINT as boolean and any other integer SQL types as integers.

```
My\SampleBundle\Entity\Subject:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:

        // ...

        motion:
            type: boolean
```

Comment: Thank you. You sure made things easy for me.